# Disable onClick on part of ListItem

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` in which each `ListItem row` contains some `TextView` and an `ImageView`.

When the image is clicked some XYZ operation is performed.

But I want to disable `onClickListener` on rest of the ListItem row.

How can this be done?

Thank You[image]

Answer (score 0):

just disable the clickable for the Listview  add the `android:onclick="call"` attribute to the  `imageview`

and declare call method on the corresponding activity of the Listview.

```
public void call(View view){

//do Something

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "play" with ListView settings:

```
// Enable elements inside listview
myListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
//disable the focus on the whole list items
myListView.setFocusable(false);
myListView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
myListView.setClickable(false);
```

Next you need to add the attribute `onClick` in your imageview

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:onClick="function"
        />
```

Function

```
public void function(View v)
    {
        ...

    }
```